# Best practice to use UIImages inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: caching, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview, uiimageview

If I'm loading images from the phone into a TableView about 50-60 entries, which method suits best?

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"page02Background.png"];
```

OR

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"page02Background" ofType:@"png"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIImage imageNamed:@"page02Background.png"];

In my point of view tableviewcell is autorelease object. so first one is best.

if u have used many bundles and put images according to the bundle .then specifying the second one is best.

advantage of this second one is u may use same imagename with different bundle (if had same imagename but different photo in different bundle).

it depending upon ur needs u have to choose which is best suit for u.

Comment: if u have any doubt u can meet us in iphone/ipad chat room